# GA4 not showing campaign under First User Campain

Tags: google-analytics-4

I have the following example URL:

https://example.com/page/?utm_source=Angelo&utm_medium=SOME_MEDIUM&utm_campaign=Marketing&utm_content=Angelo2023&utm_term=SOME_TERM

When I visit my website with this link, I can see myself as a visitor in the "realtime tab", but when I go to User acquisition and filter on First user campaign it does not show up there.

Does anyone know what might be wrong? I haven't made any changes in GA4 or added custom events or such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a gap between realtime report and standard report or other report

[[GA4] Data freshness](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11198161?hl=en)

You can wait until next day or couple of hours that it might shows up.

But if you want to see the `final` attribution. See the data 2 days ago is almost right.